# find cout of specific day between two date php without using any loop?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to find out count of a specific Day between two date.
I can do this by using loop between two date, but if there is difference of 10 years(suppose) between date loop will run 10*365 times.
Is any easier way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it php or java? you tagged java also.

Comment: i need logic only . php will be preferred.

Comment: need to trim the date interval up to the specified weekdays and then simple arithmetic will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function countDays($day, $start, $end)
{

```
$start = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);
$datediff = $end - $start;

$days =  floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));


//get the day of the week for start and end dates (0-6)
$w = array( date('w', $start ), date('w', $end) );

//get partial week day count
if ($w[0] < $w[1])
{            
    $partialWeekCount = ($day >= $w[0] && $day <= $w[1]);
}else if ($w[0] == $w[1])
{
    $partialWeekCount = $w[0] == $day;
}else
{
    $partialWeekCount = ($day >= $w[0] 
    $day <= $w[1]); 
} 
//first count the number of complete weeks, then add 1 if $day falls in a partial week. 
return intval($days / 7) + $partialWeekCount;
```

}

Function Call - countDays( 5, "2017-04-14", "2017-04-21")

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for date_diff() function. The date_diff() function returns the difference between two DateTime objects.

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

To find occurrence of specific day (for eg: Sunday). Please note: I have used 7 for Sunday. You can use 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday and so on

```
$cnt  = 0;
$start = new DateTime("2013-03-15");
$end   = new DateTime("2013-12-12");
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    if ($dt->format('N') == 7)
    {
        $cnt++;
    }
}
echo $cnt;
```

Comment: It wiil give me total number of days between two dates. I need how many Sunday(or any day ) were there.

Comment: I can do this by using loop between two date, but if there is difference of 10 years(suppose) between date loop will run 10*365 times. Timeout execution. Is any easier way to do this?