# get the difference between 2 date & time by hours, minutes and seconds using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get the difference between a datetime and a current datetime using cakephp . I succeeded to get it but I want to convert it to only hours ,minutes and seconds .

here is my code  :

```
$currDateTime = Time::now();

$date1 = $plan->start_day->format('Y-m-d');
$date2 = $currDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
$diff = abs(strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)) ;

$time1 = $plan->start_day->format('H:i:s');
$time2 = $currDateTime->format('H:i:s');
$seconds = abs(strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2));
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
$secs = floor($seconds % 60);
```

the result is a difference in years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds. 
how can I convert it to only H:m:s ??

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448587/find-cout-of-specific-day-between-two-date-php-without-using-any-loop

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for all these calculations, simply create a `DateInterval` diff using the `diff()` method provided by the time object, and use the `days`, `h`, `i`, and `s` values it provides to create your desired output. The only calculation that would be required, would be to add the days in hours.

```
$diff = $currDateTime->diff($plan->start_day);
$formatted = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($diff->days * 24) + $diff->h, $diff->i, $diff->s);
```

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Date/Time > DateTimeInterface > DateTimeInterface::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)**
- **[PHP Manual > Date/Time > DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)**